# API call being rejected when using promises

Tags: reactjs, api, promise

Im new to react and promises and i've currently got a error which i am unsure about, i am calling an API and it is being rejected within the promise. In the code i have console logged the API endpoint see if that where the error lies but it works completely fine.

Below is my code;

```
export function LoginAPICall(type, firstname, email, password){
  let baseURL = 'http://40.121.111.11:8020/';
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(baseURL + type + '/' + firstname + '/' + email + '/' + password);
    return fetch(baseURL + type + '/' + firstname + '/' + email + '/' + password)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      resolve("Success");
      return responseJson.json();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Error");
      reject("Ting is messed");
    });
  })
}
```

Here is where it is being user;

```
  login = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.firstname);
    LoginAPICall('login', this.state.firstname, this.state.email, this.state.password).then(( result ) => {
      console.log(result);
    })
  }
```

Error;

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token L in JSON at position 0
```

Any help/suggestions on this code would be appreciated!

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: what's the `error`?

Comment: @Federkun i have added the error

Comment: not that, the previous error. `console.log("Error", error);`

Comment: @Federkun The error i added in the post is the only error i get in the console, and when i added in `console.log("Error", error);` and ran the app, only thing that got printed out was `Error` even when i removed the string from the console.log()

Comment: Instead of `reject('Ting is messed')` try doing `reject(error)` to see the actual error. It's bad practice for a rejection to be a string

Comment: @apokryfos Yes that is true, i added the error in the `reject` and got `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token L in JSON at position 0`

Comment: cool; so: you have two `response.json()`, and I guess the first one is not valid json either. try to print `response.text()`, see what you are working on

Comment: @Federkun so i removed `.then((response) => response.json())` and the error is gone, but the response of the API does not get printed even with a `console.log(responseJson)`

Answer (score 0):

This error usually happens when there is an issue with the returned data (it looks like it may not be proper JSON so it can't be parsed correctly with.json()), but it you may want to try `response.data.json()` instead of just `response.json()`,

I would also try to console.log the response to see what it contains.

Answer (score 0):

First of all fetch will return a promise so you don't need an another one. You also can't call .json() twice (I think).

```
export default LoginAPICall = (type, firstname, email, password) =>
  fetch(`http://40.121.111.11:8020/${type}/${firstname}/${email}/${password}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

if that is not working it is because you don't get a valid JSON response from the backend.